# npm install -g firebase-tools gives an error

Tags: command-line-interface, npm-install

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.firebase-tools-ENG41nb9
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.firebase-tools-ENG41nb9'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.firebase-tools-ENG41nb9'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.firebase-tools-ENG41nb9'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/avi/.npm/_logs/2023-02-19T08_22_34_901Z-debug-0.log
```

while i am  installing the firebase this is the error what get and due to that i am unable to update the cli it says it is not allowed to rename the file(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.firebase-tools-ENG41nb9) and same kind of error it is giving me when i tried to update npm using the command npm install npm@latest -g, It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user i dont know what permission is it asking for any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

"This error indicates a permission issue, and it's suggesting that you use the **sudo** command to install **firebase-tools** globally using npm. Here are the steps to resolve it:

Open your terminal or command prompt with administrator privileges.

Run the following command to install firebase-tools globally using npm:

```
sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Using 'sudo' grants the necessary permissions to install the tool globally. After running this command, you should be able to use 'firebase-tools' without any permission-related issues."